# In Stack Chat room ScrollBar keep blinking in Mac Safari

Tags: bug, design, chat

Today I started using **Safari(Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7))** as my default browser and tried exploring stuff, Everything was fine except chat room scrollbar.. It keep blinking, after a interval of 1-2 seconds.

### [image]

I also tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> but still having same issue.

Please suggest if I am wrong .. or missing something in safari settings :)

Comment: old but maybe related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245049/chat-intermittently-experiences-good-vibrations